# How to update Global state correctly?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm working on an e-comerce type application. I was implementing the cart functionality but I got stuck and can't seem to find a way.

Basically I've a global state called cart. which looks like this:

```
cart: [
        {
          book: {},
          quantity: 1
        }
     ]
```

I want to update the quantity when a book is found in it.

```
case "ADD_TO_CART":
  let book_index = state.cart.findIndex(
    (el) => el.book._id === action.payload._id
  );
  let newCart;
  if (book_index === -1){
    newCart = state.cart.concat({book: action.payload, quantity: 1})
  } else {
     newCart = [...state.cart];
     newCart[book_index].quantity = newCart[book_index].quantity + 1; 
  }
  return {
    ...state,
    cart: newCart,
  };
```

The problem in it is that when a book is found, it updates the quantity by a factor of 2. So the quantity goes like 1, 3, 5, 7 so on.
I tried to replace 1 by 0.5 to see if it's doubling it and it's not.

Comment: Because your newCart[book_index].quantity is already incremented by one and after that you are manually doing  + 1 in that. So you are not getting the correct number of books. Better if you share more code on it.

Comment: That's pretty much all the logic but I'll still explain the whole structure. I have a component named 'Card'. when I click on add to cart, it calls a function (from global state using context api), and provides the book in it. The function in State goes like this. dispatch({type: "ADD_TO_CART", payload: book}). and which further goes to above mentioned code